# Hide sub sub categories in woocommerce category widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I want to remove all **sub sub categories** from the woocommerce category widget. Any idea how to accomplish this with php?

Comment: with php I cannot able to find out exact way but with css you can do this.

Comment: I love the nth of type css selector for swift hack and slash - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp